# How to switch to a desired layout using a command?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I often press `alt+F2` or `Super+R` to quickly run something. I know where to edit keybindings, so I can add an extra-action (a command to execute) to those hotkeys. Action that I want to add is *switch-to-english-layout* action. Here's my `localectl status` output, if something else can help you, request it in comments.

```
   System Locale: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: us,ru
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Variant: ,
     X11 Options: grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

UPD: I have no ibus installed and I hope it's not neccessary to invoke this buggy piece of crap just to switch the layouts

Comment: sorry, not familiar with openbox. but try using ibus

Comment: @Zeus77 You are wrong. There is **NO** difference whether you know Openbox or not. I have uninstalled ibus and everything related to it since I don't use it. Things related to keyboard are no-how connected to the window manager I use, I already regret mentioning it and I'm removing the reference to it immediately.

Comment: i said i don't know about openbox because, im not sure it has a GUI or not. and ibus, can and does change keyboard layout. also it **IS** related to the dm you're using cuz, KDE's setting for example doesn't work the same as GNOME's.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the default *XInput* instead of **ibus** or such.

You can run `setxkbmap [your layout]` from a terminal window or in console mode.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but before trying I would like to hear a clarification from you. Does this command only switch current layout to the layout with provided # **OR** does it re-set current layout choice with settings which presents only layout with provided #?

Comment: it basically sets the provided layout as default. as far as i can tell, it only supports one layout at a time, so there is no switch, it replaces whatever you're using right now. however a clever idea for you might be to create a small bash script that emulates a toggle of sorts, and then set it up with the hotkey.

Comment: Sounds awful, but I guess I'll end up doing that

Answer (score -1):

How it works for me is: System Settings->Text Entry. Here you can set any key-combo (default: Super+Space) for switching the next/previous language layout. And it shows the language in the top-right corner, so this one worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).